# Accidentally set screen resolution too high, it won't change back

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, vmware

I'm using VMware with Arch and XFCE. The default screen resolution was too small for me so I wanted to change it to something higher. I accidentally selected a screen size that was too big and I thought it was going to go back to the screen size it was before but it just stayed as a black screen. I have rebooted VMware and Arch is still a black screen.

Is there anyway to fix this without reinstalling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to find the config file that is changed, and edit it to the correct resolution. But I'm not an XFCE user so you'll have to look for this yourself :)

Another, desktop-agnostic way is to change the resolution using `xrandr`. Assuming you can still boot up your computer and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access a command prompt, you can type this to change to automatic resolution:

```
xrandr --display :0 --output VGA1 --auto
```

After the command has finished without any error you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the GUI and it should have the right resolution. Don't forget to change the resolution again, so that the configuration will be saved.

Notes:

1. You may need to change `VGA1` to the name of your display output (type `xrandr --display:0` to see the outputs).
2. If `--auto` isn't smart enough you can change it to e.g.
   `xrandr --display :0 --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768`
   , which will change the resolution to 1024x768 (again, type `xrandr --display:0` to see the possible resolution modes).

Comment: And failing all that, you can append `single` to the end of the kernel line in the `grub` boot menu, which will let you reconfigure X from single-user mode.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this exact issue today and the `xrandr` command above didn't work for me.

The actual config file is: `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`

Changed the `Resolution` line back to `800x600` and i was good:

```
<property name="Resolution" type="string" value="800x600"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to get xrandr to work is that you need to put a sleep command in before the xrandr command, run it and switch back to the X session (hold alt and left arrow) so the X session is in the foregroud before xrandr actually runs.
In my case the output is HDMI-1 so the commandline is:

```
sleep 5;xrandr --display :0 --output HDMI-1 --auto
```

I ran that and promptly switched the X session into the foreground